Nextjs serve lots of static files (images) with dynamic file name
I have several hundreds of images for a dynamically growing image gallery build with nextjs. Images are inside the public folder and can be shown with
import image1 from '../../public/image1.png'

// this works
<img src={image1.src} />

How can I dynamically show images without creating an import for each of the images up front like so?
// doesnt work
let imgId = 5
<img src=`../../public/image${imgId}.png` />

I also tried the built in Image component like so but without luck:
// doesnt work
<Image 
    src={"/image/" + imgId + ".png"}
    height="100" 
    width="100" 
    alt="image" 
/>

Also the solution with require.context() will not work as nextjs does not use webpack.

This question is similar to: Any easy way to import multiple image files at once in react. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

require.context is not available: I am getting an error message: Property 'context' does not exist on type 'NodeRequire'.ts(2339)

Dynamic loading and lazy loading will not work as well: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading

Based on this answer from here my solution is using an api:
Create a file named [image].ts within the public/api/ folder
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const { images } = req.query
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpg");
  const filePath = path.resolve(".", `public/img/ai/${image}`);
  const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

  return res.send(imageBuffer);
}


Anything in public directory should be accessible with absolute path.
If there is an "image.jpg" in /public directory it should be accessible with https://yourdomain/image.jpg.
// ✅ These work

<img src="image.jpg" />
<img src="/image.jpg" />
<Image src="/image.jpg" width={100} height={100} />


// ❌ These don't work (missing leading /)
<Image src="image.jpg" width={100} height={100}/>


Not in nextjs as 'The public folder can only serve those files that were included at build time.' See here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets
